# Moment.js with a format zulu and format date javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have this format date:

- `01Mar-0234`
- `26Feb-0430`

`01` is day, `mar` or `feb` is mounth and `0430` is 4 oclock 30 in formater zulu `+00`.
I would like to use moment for converting this format, I'm trying this:

```
moment('26Feb-0430').format("DD-MM-YY HH:MM");
```

but I haven't good format and I have this error :

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment c
onstruction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and version
s. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major r
elease. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
```

Can you help me for have `26/02/2017 06:30` for summer and `5h30` winter?

Comment: Did you go to the link in that error message? Because it's pretty clear what you need to do to to fix it. There's also http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments and in the warning message you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parsing function.

In the format string parameter you have to use moment tokens where: `DD` is day of the month. `MMM` is month's short name, `HH` is 0-23 hours and `mm` (lowercase) is minutes.

Since you have to threat your input as `+00:00`, you have to use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display the parsed moment object passing the tokens you need, always remember that moment tokens are case sensitive.

Here a working sample:

```js
var result = moment.utc('26Feb-0430', 'DDMMM-HH:mm').format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i'm try this :moment.utc(eta, 'DDMMM-HH:mm').local().format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"); but i have one probleme 
I have a problem it does + 1 hour but with summer time and winter time we have more 2h for the time summer time and
Plus one h in winter time how to handle this